# Cannot get microphone to work on new wireless headset on Windows laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone

I Just recently got a pair of "Power Beats 3 Wireless", but I cannot get the microphone to work on my laptop (HP Notebook - 15-ay196nr: Windows 10).

This is currently where I am at with trying to figure this issue out.

1. The mic works on my phone and a different Windows 10 laptop
2. I have a pair of iHome wireless earbuds that has a working mic on my
   laptop.
3. The output audio works fine on my laptop, just mic that has issues.
4. Under bluetooth setting it shows that both Audio and Voice are
   connected
5. Under audio settings the mic shows up under input devices. Doing the
   mic test from this screen does not work, my voice is not detected
   when i talk. No other mic based app I have tried detects my voice
   either.
6. I have made sure that the Mic is my default input device
7. I verified the mic audio is 100% (not muted)
8. I have run Windows Update and HP Support Assistant to make sure all
   HP drivers are updated
9. I have uninstalled the "Beats" drivers from Device manager.
   Reconnected my headset reinstalls the drivers successfully.

I am not sure where to go from here. Any ideas would be appreciated!

EDIT:

10. On "Sound Devices" I noticed that headset portion appears in both input and output devices.  So i tried disabling the output portion in case in was conflicting but all that did was completely remove the "voice" from #4 above.
11. I also confirmed that the bluetooth service of "Handsfree Telephony" was enabled for this device

Comment: Make sure you're using hands free profile (HFP or HSP) and not stereo profile A2DP. Although when I test in old style sound settings in windows 10 it seems to automatically switch for showing that microphone testbar, so that's probably not it.

Comment: @KoenG.I think i'm ok on that end, but your proposal did get me looking in a different direction.  I updated my post with some additional things I checked out